# Expand element to fit rest of container inside table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a container inside another element expand to its parent height without using JavaScript.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate what I mean:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">
    middle
    <div id="container">This should fill up the rest of the #middle div</div>
</div>
<div id="right">Left<br><br><br><br><br><br>This one is longer than the #middle</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left, #middle, #right { 
    display: table-cell; 
    background: #eee;  
    border: #ccc 1px solid; 
}

#container { background: red; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubm7eyu8/)

[image: expand element inside table-cell]

I didn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to work with `display:table-cell;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply substitute the `display:table-cell;` with an outer flexbox, that allows the middle column to be a vertical flexbox, which in turn supports the auto-growing you want to achieve.

```
body {display: flex;}
#middle {display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
#container {background-color:red;flex-grow:1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding  `display:inline-flex;` and `height:100%;` to `#container` will do it. Do same to any of the DIV's that you want to fill whole space.

```css
#left, #middle, #right { 
    display: table-cell; 
    background: #eee;  
    border: #ccc 1px solid; 
}

#container { 
    background: red;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">
    middle
    <div id="container">This should fill up the rest of the #middle div</div>
</div>
<div id="right">Left<br><br><br><br><br><br>This one is longer than the #middle</div>
```

Comment: But this will make the container overlap its parent element: http://jsfiddle.net/ubm7eyu8/1/

Comment: It didn't overlap and you can manage the overlap and margins as desired. Also see the method here http://jsfiddle.net/ubm7eyu8/3/

Comment: checked on chrome too. see if you mistyped anything.

Comment: Doesn't "work" for me too, OP is going for height, not width.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set relative position to #middle and and absolute postion to #container and also set top and bottom appropriately of #containner, after this you will have to set the width of middle also.

```css
#left,
#middle,
#right {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #eee;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}
#container {
  background: red;
  top: 13%;
  height:86%;
}
#middle {
  width: 200px;
  height:128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">
  middle
  <div id="container">This should fill up the rest of the #middle div</div>
</div>
<div id="right">Left
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>This one is longer than the #middle</div>
```

**Editted**

I have updated the above code and it is independent of position style of any element.

Answer (score -1):

If it's purely visuell you can just turn the bg-colors around:

Set

```
#middle {
    background: red
}
```

and

```
#middle-top {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee
}
```

This way it looks like the bottom part is filling up the rest, but you just set the top to look the same like the rest. ;)

And here the complete snippet: or a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBRxGb)

```css
#left, #middle, #right { 
    display: table-cell; 
    background: #eee;  
    border: #ccc 1px solid; 
}

#middle {
    background: red
}

#middle-top {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">
  <div id="middle-top">middle</div>
  This should fill up the rest of the #middle div
</div>
<div id="right">Left<br><br><br><br><br><br>This one is longer than the #middle</div>
```